# Add files to an existing zip archive via JSZip

Tags: javascript, jquery, jszip

I have a zip file which is a Visual Basic project. What I'm trying to see is if I can add my web app as a directory inside this zip archive so I can easily export my web apps as native windows apps

I tried the Ajax method from the [documentation](http://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/howto/read_zip.html) and it worked fine on my hard drive when loaded in Firefox, but it's not calling when from my [website](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/app/)!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".download").on("click", function() {
    JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent('YourWinApp.zip', function(err, data) {
      if(err) {
        throw err; // or handle err
      }

      var zip = new JSZip(data);
      zip.file("Hello.txt", "Hello World\n");
      var folder = zip.folder("images");
      folder.file("folder.txt", "I'm a file in a new folder");
      var content = zip.generate({type:"blob"});
      // see FileSaver.js
      saveAs(content, "example.zip");
    });

  });
});
```

Comment: How do you include it ? With the file in jszip `dist/` folder ?

Comment: `require is not defined` is the error. gee maybe __`require` is not defined in your project__? The tutorial probably uses RequireJS

Comment: I got it to work on my hard drive locally on my machine, but doesn't call on my website. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried the Ajax method from the documentation and it worked perfectly! (I didn't link to the right file lol)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".download").on("click", function() {
    JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent('YourWindowsApp.zip', function(err, data) {
      if(err) {
        throw err; // or handle err
      }

      var zip = new JSZip(data);
      zip.file("Hello.txt", "Hello World\n");
      var folder = zip.folder("images");
      folder.file("folder.txt", "I'm a file in a new folder");
      var content = zip.generate({type:"blob"});
      // see FileSaver.js
      saveAs(content, "example.zip");
    });

  });
});
```